# Thumbnail is corrupt but image is good

Tags: thumbnails

I am using wordpress 3.5 to manage my website with a template (not sure which). Lately, each picture I add to a gallery creates a corrupted thumbnail, but the picture itself shows up ok. I tried uploading pictures that used to create a proper thumbnail and now their new thumbnail is broken.

[The broken thumbnail link](http://www.startupbootcamp.org/wp-content/gallery/mentors-israel/alexander-babitsky.jpg?i=1063142804%22%20class=%22shutter%22%20title=%22alexander-babitsky.jpg%22%3E%20%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%3Cimg%20class=%22thumb%22%20src=%22http://www.startupbootcamp.org/wp-content/gallery/mentors-israel/thumbs/thumbs_alexander-babitsky.jpg?i=470070297%22%20id=%22thumb1534%22%3E%20%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%3C/a%3E) - though it opens up correctly...

[image: broken thumbnail]

How can set to fix this?

Comment: There appears to be the right half of a HTML `<a>` element on the end of the thumbnail URL you've posted

Comment: I'll check though it is probably a problem in the copy and paste since I used Chrome's F12 Elements to track it down and probably didn't copy all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to reset the thumbnail settings in your [media settings](http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_Media_Screen), then regenerate the thumbnail; either:

- use [Regenerate Thumbnails](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/) plugin to rebuild all thumbnails; or
- edit image / rotate it left / rotate it right (back to original) / save image

Comment: I'm a bit tipsy on installing new plugins on a live site. Editing the thumbnail is not possible right now as it opens the overlay and then immediately closes down

Comment: Hmmm... check your _wp_attachment_metadata for that image, maybe it's broken/lost. It should be a serialised PHP array. See [this tale of woe](http://snippets.webaware.com.au/snippets/repair-wordpress-image-meta/) for more details.

Comment: I second that plugin... It's a lifesaver on almost every project I work on.