# Regenerate missing _wp_attachment_metadata

Tags: images, post-meta, attachments, media-library

For some reason, some of the thumbnails of my media library are randomly becoming missing.

I've found out `_wp_attachment_metadata` isn't present in the database for those images with missing thumbnails. The files, however, are present on disk - both the original file and the "cropped" sizes.

---

### ***The purpose of this question is not to find out why this happens***, I wrote a [different question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/330267/22510) for that.

**Again, in this context all I want is to fix the symptoms, while I haven't found out the cause yet.**

---

My goal here is rebuilding the missing thumbnails.

What I've already tried:

- [This WP SE answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/78542/22510).
- The [Regenerate Thumbnails](https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/) plugin:

  - If I open the attachment details panel for that specific image and press the "Regenerate thumbnails" button, I get the following message: "ERROR: Unable to load the metadata for this attachment."
  - Running "Regenerate Thumbnails For All 4028 Attachments" works, but it takes a long time (1 hour for 4.000 pictures), even with the "Skip regenerating existing correctly sized thumbnails" option turned on.
- The [Fix My Posts](https://wordpress.org/plugins/fix-my-posts/) plugin: displays a meter which goes from 0% to 100% in a few seconds, but no difference.
- The [Fix Media Library](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wow-media-library-fix/) plugin: even when selecting "Regenerate attachments metadata and thumbnails", it takes about 1 second per image. It also errors out on very large images, so for me it processes about 100 images and then stops.

I've also come across the following snippet that is supposed to fix the missing metadata, but it isn't working as intended (see details after code)

```
/**
* fix broken image metadata so that thumbs can be regenerated
*/

function fixImageMeta() {
    global $wpdb;

    $sql = "
        select ID from {$wpdb->posts}
        where post_type = 'attachment'
        and post_mime_type like 'image/%'
    ";
    $images = $wpdb->get_col($sql);

    foreach ($images as $id) {
        $meta = wp_get_attachment_metadata($id);
        if (!$meta) {
            $file = get_attached_file($id);
            if (!empty($file)) {
                $info = getimagesize($file);
                $meta = array (
                    'width' => $info[0],
                    'height' => $info[1],
                    'hwstring_small' => "height='{$info[1]}' width='{$info[0]}'",
                    'file' => basename($file),
                    'sizes' => array(),         // thumbnails etc.
                    'image_meta' => array(),    // EXIF data
                );
                update_post_meta($id, '_wp_attachment_metadata', $meta);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

([source](https://snippets.webaware.com.au/snippets/repair-wordpress-image-meta/))

The above code fixes the missing thumbnails on the media library, but with some inconsistencies:

Unserialized `_wp_attachment_metadata` for a previously correct image:

```
Array
(
    [width] => 700
    [height] => 430
    [file] => 2019/02/filename.png
    [sizes] => Array
        (
            [thumbnail] => Array
                (
                    [file] => filename-150x150.png
                    [width] => 150
                    [height] => 150
                    [mime-type] => image/png
                )

            [medium] => Array
                (
                    [file] => filename-300x184.png
                    [width] => 300
                    [height] => 184
                    [mime-type] => image/png
                )

        )

    [image_meta] => Array
        (
            [aperture] => 0
            [credit] => 
            [camera] => 
            [caption] => 
            [created_timestamp] => 0
            [copyright] => 
            [focal_length] => 0
            [iso] => 0
            [shutter_speed] => 0
            [title] => 
            [orientation] => 0
            [keywords] => Array
                (
                )

        )

)
```

Unserialized `_wp_attachment_metadata` for a "fixed" image:

```
Array
(
    [width] => 700
    [height] => 430
    [hwstring_small] => height='430' width='700'
    [file] => filename.png
    [sizes] => Array
        (
        )

    [image_meta] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

Comment: Did you, by any chance find the cause? Your other post has been deleted.

Comment: @Tim no, didn't find the cause, unfortunately.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Running the [`wp media regenerate` command](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/media/regenerate/) from WP-CLI with the `--only-missing` argument is quite fast (takes about 30 seconds for 4000 images) and rebuilds `_wp_attachment_metadata` correctly:

`wp media regenerate --only-missing`

Answer (score 1):

There are some non-working links above, so if somebody still struggling with this in 2021 (specially after moving WP), I found a working solution here:

https://barebones.dev/articles/rebuild-meta-data-for-media-items-that-are-missing-it/

Saving for the future the origin source, but I had to remove the meta query to work well. (took quite long time for a few hundred attachments, so consider to build in a counter and do some from-to limiter inside the foreach, as limiting the posts_per_page won't work well, only if you order by rand, and run lots of times, but it's not a good idea :))

```
require_once('wp-load.php');
if ( ! function_exists( 'wp_crop_image' ) ) {
    include( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );
}

$attachments = get_posts(
[
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'fields' => 'ids',
    'meta_query' => [
        [
            'key' => '_wp_attachment_metadata',
            'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
        ]
    ]
]
);

foreach($attachments as $attachment_id)
{

    $url = get_attached_file($attachment_id);

    if (strpos($url, '.svg') !== false) continue;

    $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata($attachment_id, $url);
    wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attachment_id,  $attach_data );

}
```

Comment: Do you think you could add some more detail on how exactly you got this working? when I add this to an existing page or a new page it does nothing.

Answer (score -2):

The real problem with your website is "thumbnails of my media library are randomly becoming missing" and that's what you should try to fix at the first place.
And you gave a hint right in your message why it happens: "It also errors out on very large images". It happens because webserver goes out of RAM when it tries to build thumbnails for your images. Potentially other images are converted on it's edge so they fail randomly.

You need to upgrade your hosting plan or use/upload smaller images.

Comment: You seem to have missed the large, bold letters stating that I'm aware of the need to fix the root issue and wrote a different question addressing it: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/330267/22510 - you're welcome to add these considerations there.